# RunonUI Thread blocks a AsynTask in android from executing to completion

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have an issue with runOnuiThread and AsyncTask getting called together.

My AsynchTask gets data to populate a listView through runOnUIThread call.
This Asych Task can get data even when UI is not in focus . It starts from a UI screen and runs until application is logged out.
Now data coming from this Task can populate only a particular listview. 
Now if i invoke another Asynch Task from another view  using call executeOnExecutor call for AsynchTask, the Asynch Task does not run to compeltion. It locks up.
If I comment out code for the never ending AsychTask called Receiver.. then all UI's listview get populated and no  Asych Task locks.
This Receiver waits on a REST API call for response to return but since I am running through executeonExecutor call, it should be parallel processing.
I need to have the receiver running all the time as that is an integral of my application. 
What strategy can I use here to fix this issue.
Here are my code snippets.

```
public class Receiver  {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    private String m_ErrorMessage;
    private IRunOnUIThreadCallback iRunOnUIThreadCallback;
   private Send m_Received;
    private int m_TimeoutDuration;//how long the reading of new message waits in milli seconds

    public void SetCallback(IRunOnUIThreadCallback runOnUIThreadCallback)
    {
        iRunOnUIThreadCallback = runOnUIThreadCallback;
    }
    public void SetTimeoutDuration(int timeout)
    {
        m_TimeoutDuration = timeout;
    }
    public void StartReceiver(Send receiverInfo)
    {
         String receivedInfo = null;
        try {
            new ReceiveInfo ().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, receiverInfo);
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            m_ErrorMessage = exp.getMessage();
        }
    }
    private class ReceiveInfo extends AsyncTask<Send, Void, Send>
    {
        //initiate vars
        public receive() {
            super();
            //my params here
        }
        protected Message doInBackground(Send... receiverInfo)
        {
                            Send recv=null;
            try {

                PreferenceSingleton single = PreferenceSingleton.getInstance();
                final User user = single.getUser();
                final SvcApi svc = LoginAuthSvc.init();


                Send send=(Send)receiverInfo[0];
                send.setUserId(user.getUsername());
                //dxbrem
                while (true) {

                    recv=svc.receive(send);
                    String str= recv.get();
                    if ((str == null || (str.trim().length() == 0))) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    //DJ uncomment
                   iRunOnUIThreadCallback.RunAfterIsReceived(recv);
                    //messages.add(message);
                    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + recv + "'");

                }

            }catch(Exception exp)
            {
                m_ErrorMessage = exp.getMessage();
            }

            return recv;
        }
    }
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return m_ErrorMessage;
    }
}

public interface IRunOnUIThreadCallback {
    public void RunAfterIsReceived(ByteSent m);
    public void RunAfterIsReceived(Send m);
}
```

The class that handles this.. has the following code and

```
 public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements MFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, IRunOnUIThreadCallback {

    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public void SetUICallbackOnMessageReceiver()
        {
            mReceiver.SetCallback(this);
        }

     private void callRunUIThread(final SentInfo m) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (m!= null) {
                        mGridArray.add(message);
                        if (mListAdapter != null) {
                            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mListView.setSelection(mListAdapter.getCount());
                            mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mListAdapter.getCount());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }); // end of runOnUiThread
        }

     @Override
        public void RunAfterIsReceived(ByteSent m) {

        }

        @Override
            public void RunAfterIsReceived(Sent m) {
                SentInfo m= new SentInfo(false, recv.getInfo());
                callRunUIThread(msg);
            }
```

mListAdapter is the ListAdapater
mListView is the ListView

Here is the AsynchTask code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;



import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class CallableTask<T> extends AsyncTask<Void,Double,T> {

    private static final String TAG = CallableTask.class.getName();





    public static <V> void invoke(Callable<V> call,Activity activity, TaskCallback<V> callback){

        new CallableTask<V>(activity,call, callback).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
    }




    private Callable<T> callable_;
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> asyncTask_;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private Fragment fragmentActivity;
    private android.support.v4.app.Fragment dynamicFragment;

    private TaskCallback<T> callback_;

    private Exception error_;

    public CallableTask(Fragment actvy,Callable<T> callable, TaskCallback<T> callback) {
        callable_ = callable;
        callback_ = callback;
        fragmentActivity=actvy;
    }

    public CallableTask(Activity actvy,Callable<T> callable, TaskCallback<T> callback) {
        callable_ = callable;
        callback_ = callback;
        activity=actvy;
    }

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(Void... ts) {
        T result = null;
        try{
            result = callable_.call();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error invoking callable in AsyncTask callable: " + callable_, e);
            error_ = e;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T r) {
        if(error_ != null){
            callback_.error(error_);
        }
        else {
            callback_.success(r,activity);
        }
    }


    public static <V> void invoke(Callable<V> call, Fragment _frg, TaskCallback<V> callback) {
        new CallableTask<V>(_frg,call, callback).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
    }


//    public CallableTask(android.support.v4.app.Fragment chatActivity,Callable<T> callable, TaskCallback<T> callback) {
//        callable_ = callable;
//        callback_ = callback;
//        dynamicFragment=chatActivity;
//    }
public CallableTask(android.support.v4.app.Fragment actvy,Callable<T> callable, TaskCallback<T> callback) {
    callable_ = callable;
    callback_ = callback;
    dynamicFragment=actvy;
}

    public static <V> void invoke(Callable<V> call, android.support.v4.app.Fragment _frg, TaskCallback<V> callback) {
        new CallableTask<V>(_frg,call, callback).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR );
    }
}
```

This gets called  here... only when clicking on a button Send.

```
 CallableTask.invoke(new Callable<Sent>() {


            @Override
            public Sent call() throws Exception {
        }, this, new TaskCallback<Sent>() {

            @Override
            public void success(Sent result, Context context) {
mGridArray.add(result);
                            if (mListAdapter != null) {
                                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                mListView.setSelection(mListAdapter.getCount());
                                mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mListAdapter.getCount());
}
@Override
            public void error(Exception e) {
           }
        });
```

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: Wouldn't a Service be a better choice for a long-running task than AsyncTask?

Comment: I was reading about Service but I do not understand how I can interface a Service for a long running task and how would it be able to populate the UI ?Especially when I leave that UI ListView and move to another one.

Comment: Well if that ListView isn't on screen any more, there's nothing to update, right?

Comment: I finally resolved this by running a Asynch.cancel call on the thread from the activity fragment that started this thread. when I move away from activity. If I did not , it blocked any other tasks from running,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by running a Asynch.cancel call on the thread from the activity fragment that started this thread. when I move away from activity. If I did not , it blocked any other tasks from running,